# Can you define a variable inside an if statement?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a variable inside an if statement but it won't allow it. Is there any other way to do what I'm trying?

```
print ('Type numbers 1 or 2')
c = int(input())

if c == 1:
    answer = (90) #so the variable "answer" will be set to '90' if the user types "1"

if c == 2:
    answer = (50)

print (answer)
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it won't allow it".  If you get an error message, include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: Your code works as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will run in the expected way if either `1` or `2` are entered as input. But if user inputs another number, you will get an `Exception`:

```
NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
```

To avoid this, you could declare the variable `answer` before the `if` statements:

```
answer = 0    # or a reasonable number

if c == 1:
    answer = 90
# ...
```

**Note:** The `()` in `answer = (90)` are not necessary since it's a single number.

Comment: How would I go about making answer = (+) or subtration?

Comment: If `answer` is already defined, you can do `answer = answer + something` or simply `answer += something`

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the possibility that your `input()` might be out of your preconceived options:

```
c = int(input("Type no. 1 or 2: "))

if c==1: 
    answer=90
    print(answer)
elif c==2: 
    answer =50
    print(answer)
else:
    print("you input neither 1 nor 2")
```

Here's a more compact solution using `assert`:

```
c = int(input("Type no. 1 or 2: "))
assert c in [1,2], "You input neither 1 nor 2."
answer = 90 if c == 1 else 50
print(answer)
```